sum of projected area and a generalization of Oppenheim's inequality
From this post:

In $\mathbb R^4$, let $U$ be a 2D plane, let $\pi_1$ be the projection from $U$ onto $xy$-plane and $\pi_2$ be the projection from $U$ onto $zw$-plane, then $\det\pi_1+\det\pi_2\le1$, and $\det\pi_1+\det\pi_2=1$ if and only if $\pi_1,\pi_2$ both preserve angles (same as similarity transformations in Euclidean geometry).

From this answer the projected area by $\pi_1$ equals $\det\pi_1$ times the actual area. Then for an arbitrary triangle $△_3$ in $\Bbb R^4$ with vertices $(x_i,y_i,z_i,w_i),i=1,2,3$
Let $U$ be the plane of triangle $△_3$.
Let $\pi_1$ be the projection from $U$ onto $xy$-plane and $\pi_2$ be the projection from $U$ onto $zw$-plane.
$△_1=\pi_1(△_3)$ is a triangle with vertices $(x_i,y_i,0,0),i=1,2,3$
denote the length of its sides by $a,b,c$
$△_2=\pi_2(△_3)$ is a triangle with vertices $(0,0,z_i,w_i),i=1,2,3$
denote the length of its sides by $d,e,f$
Then $a^2=(x_2-x_3)^2+(y_2-y_3)^2,d^2=(z_2-z_3)^2+(w_2-w_3)^2$
Then $a^2+d^2=(x_2-x_3)^2+(y_2-y_3)^2+(z_2-z_3)^2+(w_2-w_3)^2$
So the length of sides of $△_3$ is $\sqrt{a^2+d^2},\sqrt{b^2+e^2},\sqrt{c^2+f^2}$
Since $\det\pi_1+\det\pi_2\le1$ we have
$$S(△_1)+S(△_2)\le S(△_3)$$
This proves 10.12.3 in Geometric Inequalities - Bottema, et. al. (1968):

This inequality can be generalized to

Let $△_1,△_2$ be two arbitrary $n$-simplices.

There exist $n$-simplex $△_3$ such that the corresponding vertex distances satisfy
$$d_{ij}(△_1)^2+d_{ij}(△_2)^2=d_{ij}(△_3)^2$$for all $1\le i,j\le n+1$.
The corresponding altitudes satisfy
$$h_i(△_1)^2+h_i(△_2)^2\le h_i(△_3)^2$$
for all $1\le i\le n+1$.
Their volumes satisfy$\DeclareMathOperator{\vol}{Vol}$
$$\vol(△_1)^{2/n}+\vol(△_2)^{2/n}\le\vol(△_3)^{2/n}$$


Is this true?
(The case $n=2$ is the original inequality.)
If $1.$ is true then $3.$ can be proved by similar method as above:
We have $△_1=\pi_1(△_3),△_2=\pi_2(△_3)$ and
from this post

In $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, let $U$ be a $n$-dimensional hyperplane, $\Pi_1,\Pi_2$ be orthocomplement $n$-dimensional subspaces, and $\pi_i:U\to\Pi_i$ be the orthogonal projections, then $(\det\pi_1)^{2/n}+(\det\pi_2)^{2/n}\le1$

so $\vol(△_1)^{2/n}+\vol(△_2)^{2/n}\le\vol(△_3)^{2/n}$.
